# Weird Benchmarking results

Tags: apache-kafka, system-design

I have tested out 2 scenarious, request based parallelism, thread based parallelism,
cpu: 4 core

case1:
I have hosted a api, and sent 2R,4R,6R simultaneously the times are given below
2R- 50 sec
4R- 100sec
6R - 150sec
so basically If I have 12 R dividing it into 6 of 2R(300sec), 3 of 4R(300sec),2 of 6R(300sec)
all of the take the same time :?? how come this is possible

case2:
runnings n threads which take the request from kafka
the results seem similar if 2,4 are present in msg queue to be processed but for 6 they look slightly better taking 135 sec for all 6 requests in kafka.

How is it possible that running N requests at a time be almost similar, does that not use more cores and run a bit faster and then be stabilized for N>x requests here x seems to be 2!! any ideas/suggestions?

was expecting different results